# VBA not pulling through a format correctly

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I have created a userform which when entering a reference will pull through all information within the line of that reference.

I have some data in that line that is formatted 00-00-00 much like a banking sort code. The issue I am finding is although the cell displays 00-00-00 when you view it, when I click the find button on my userform it would pull through blank.

Can someone please help me with this issue please? Below is a sample of my coding The lines referring to the code I am pulling through is VL1, VL2, and VL3. Any of these sequences = 0 it will not pull through.

```
Private Sub Find_Click()

Dim searchRange As Range
Dim foundCell As Range
Dim mysearch As String

mysearch = Search.Value

With Sheets("Master Data")
    Set searchRange = Sheets("Master Data").Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

Set foundCell = searchRange.Find(what:=mysearch, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
    RDesc = foundCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
    BD.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 6).Value
    Ml.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 7).Value
    Es.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 8).Value
    In.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 9).Value
    Pr.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 10).Value
    Qt.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 11).Value
    RC.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 12).Value
    ROC.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 13).Value
    Tal.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 5).Value
    Vu.Value = Me.Total.Value / 1.2
    VT.Value = Me.Total.Value - Me.Value.Value
    R.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 17).Value
    Ap.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 18).Value
    L1.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 19).Value
    L2.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 20).Value
    Cy.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 21).Value
    P.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 22).Value
    VL1.Value = Mid(foundCell.Offset(0, 23).Value, 1, 1) & Mid(foundCell.Offset(0, 23).Value, 2, 1)
    VL2.Value = Mid(foundCell.Offset(0, 23).Value, 3, 1) & Mid(foundCell.Offset(0, 23).Value, 4, 1)
    VL3.Value = Mid(foundCell.Offset(0, 23).Value, 5, 1) & Mid(foundCell.Offset(0, 23).Value, 6, 1)
    Ar.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 24).Value
    Processed.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 25).Value
    EntryDate.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    RDat.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 27).Value
    StartDate.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 26).Value

Else
     MsgBox "Uh oh, things have gone a little sideways and the reference number " & Search.Value & " cannot be located. Please try another reference!"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace this:

```
 VL1.Value = Mid(foundCell.Offset(0, 23).Value, 1, 1) & Mid(foundCell.Offset(0, 23).Value, 2, 1)
 VL2.Value = Mid(foundCell.Offset(0, 23).Value, 3, 1) & Mid(foundCell.Offset(0, 23).Value, 4, 1)
 VL3.Value = Mid(foundCell.Offset(0, 23).Value, 5, 1) & Mid(foundCell.Offset(0, 23).Value, 6, 1)
```

To this:

```
 Dim NewValue as String
 NewValue =Format(foundCell.Offset(0, 23).Value, "00-00-00")
 VL1.Value = Mid(NewValue , 1, 2)
 VL2.Value = Mid(NewValue , 4, 2)
 VL3.Value = Mid(NewValue , 7, 2)
```